# Executing stored CSQueries

Tags: c#-4.0, csquery

I am trying to create a crawler where I need to be able to execute different queries to extract different types of data from the crawled pages. I've been looking into CsQuery for extracing the data, and it seems to work perfectly when I have a simple CSS-selector as

h4:contains('texstring')

My problem is that I need to be able to evaluate complex queries like the following:

["h4:contains('textstring')"].Parent().Parent().Find("div").Find("span").Text();

I haven't found any great solution yet. CsQuery can easily do the above, but only if I write it in the code, and since I want to be able to execute queries saved in a database, I need to be able to load and execute the queries dynamically.
My currently best idea is to make a recursive function go through the statement one dot at a time, but that would result in 6 calls to the function to be able to execute the above query. It also seems like I would end up creating functionality that is already present in CsQuery, but I can't figure out an more elegant way to solve the problems.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. First you can use reflection and regular expressions to convert the c# string from the database to an expression. There lots of small projects to do this. Another option is to host a scripting environment such as iron python or jint and write your expressions using one of those. Third option is to use the codedom and evaluate the saved string then converting to an assembly. Each option has pros and cons.

The first option uses reflection which can be very slow. But you can use c# natively. The second option uses a whole other language and requires setting up the scripting environment. But it can be easier for nonprogrammers to develop expressions for. The third option requires creating a new assembly every time the expression changes but can't be unloaded. But this option is probably the overall fastest in processing speed.

Personally I would host jint to keep the learning curve down for web folk and its environment setup would be fairly easy if all you need is the CLR proper and csquery library access.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at the options you have described :)